# Publish stream to MQTT broker

Tags: mqtt, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

For a weather station using Raspberry Pi Pico W, a Pimoroni Pico Explorer board and a BME280 breakout board I get the Raspberry Pico to publish to a topic when a button is pressed. But how to get it to publish temperature and humidity values?

My code to press the message button when I press a button on the Raspberry Pi Pico:

```
mqtt_server = 'broker.mqttdashboard.com'
client_id = 'bigles'
topic_pub = b'cherub'
topic_msg = b'Button Pressed'
```

I changed `topic_msg` to `bme280.read`. Because it's surrounded by `''` it will publish exactly what's between quotes, so I removed them:

```
topic_msg = bme280.read()
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 17
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried `topic_msg = (bme280.read())`, but got invalid syntax again. I tried:

```
temp = bme280.read()
topic_msg = 'temp'
```

Resulting in the message "temp" appearing in my broker. I defined temp as a function, only to be told it has no `len()`. Adding `len` didn't work.

```
import time
from breakout_bme280 import BreakoutBME280
from pimoroni_i2c import PimoroniI2C
from pimoroni import PICO_EXPLORER_I2C_PINS

i2c = PimoroniI2C(**PICO_EXPLORER_I2C_PINS)
bme = BreakoutBME280(i2c, address=0x76)

import network
import time
from umqtt.simple import MQTTClient

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
wlan.connect("i can hear what u sayin","12345678")
time.sleep(5)
print(wlan.isconnected())

def temp
temp = bme.read()
mqtt_server = 'broker.hivemq.com'
client_id = 'bigles'
topic_pub = b'Temp'
topic_msg =

def mqtt_connect():
    client = MQTTClient(client_id, mqtt_server, keepalive=3600)
    client.connect()
    print('Connected to %s MQTT Broker'%(mqtt_server))
    return client

def reconnect():
    print('Failed to connect to the MQTT Broker. Reconnecting...')
    time.sleep(5)
    machine.reset()

try:
    client = mqtt_connect()
except OSError as e:
    reconnect()
while True:
    if bme.read():
        client.publish(topic_pub, topic_msg)
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Following lines are incorrect- incorrect syntax
# def temp
# temp = bme.read()


mqtt_server = 'broker.hivemq.com'
client_id = 'bigles'
topic_pub = b'Temp'
topic_msg = str(bme.read())    # convert received value into string
```

Also, in your while loop, you publish the same previously recorded value `topic_msg` and never read into it again.
Also, move out sleep `time.sleep(5)` outside if, into loop

Also, suggestion to fix wifi part:

```
wlan.connect('wifi', 'pass')
while not wlan.isconnected():
    pass
print("Connected:", wlan.ifconfig())
```